IIS 10 website serving ssl certificate that does not exists
When accessing the website externally we are served an SSL certificate that was previously removed (months ago) as it was expired and a new certificate issued. I can not find any reference to the old certificate anywhere.  When running netsh http show sslcert the old certificate is not in the output, whereas the reissued certificate is.  When accessing the website on the server, the expected certificate is served correctly.
This is a Windows Server 2019 Standard and IIS 10.  The server predates me so I was not involved setting it up.  It most likely was created from an image of an existing server as it was being moved from from one hosting company to another.

Then clearly this isn't something you or anyone here can analyze and resolve, as the expired certificate is likely cached somewhere else on the wire. Please escalate to your network administrators and let them troubleshoot along the wire.

Our issue turned out to be a firewall policy that was using the expired certificate.  Once the policy was disabled, the webserver responded as expected.
